# Laptop to Phone (Twilio Programmable Video) displaying black screen

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, twilio

Does anyone know if its possible to use the Twilio Programmable video API correctly from phone to laptop. Every time I make a video call on two laptops everything works fine.

But, if I call from phone to a laptop, the laptop displays a black screen (which should be the stream of the iphone camera). Ive searched everywhere, and do not see anyone facing the same issue. I am using the javascript SDK by the way, and using Safari for the iphone, chrome for the laptop.

Comment: Can you try with Chrome on the phone?

Comment: I am having the same issue, do you have an update on whether this got resolved?

Comment: @Win the problem for is I was using createLocalTracks() to create local video. Instead I used room.localParticipant.videoTracks.values())[0].track. This gave me the local video correctly.

Comment: @matt thanks for the response. Can you expand upon what you mean? I am using the `createLocalVideoTrack` function, are you suggesting I should replace this with something else?